# Django can't find static files for an app

Tags: python, django

I have static files placed in `my_site/my_app/static/my_app/js` and `my_site/my_app/static/my_app/css`. For some reason, the code below doesn't produce any output which means it can't find the static files:

```
#my_app/templates/my_app/base.html

{% load staticfiles %}
```

Here is setting.py

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'


STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
)

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'my_app', 'static', 'my_app',).replace('\\','/'),
) 

STATIC_ROOT = ''
```

Why is that?

Comment: are you use something like this `<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/test.js' %}"></script>` for load static file?

Comment: @HasanRamezani, I showed what I use.

Comment: where? I see just `{% load staticfiles %}`.

Comment: @HasanRamezani, yes, that is it. Should there be anything else? I just want to load them all at once.

Comment: see my answer, I post sample html file, that use static file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `django.contrib.staticfiles` to `INSTALLED_APPS` in your `settings.py`.

Remove `STATICFILES_FINDERS`, `STATICFILES_DIRS`, `STATIC_ROOT` from your `settings.py`.

change your `base.html` to something like this:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fa">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'my_app/js/app.js' %}"></script>
        <title>{{ title }}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block content %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 1) What does `{% load staticfiles %}` mean? 2) That's not working, it loads the files from the base directory, not from the application directory.

Comment: is there any way to load them all at once?

Comment: all at once? what is your mean?

Comment: like in Rails - recursively, without having to specify each file.

Comment: @Grienders I have added my answer which worked out for me. Check it if it helps you too

Comment: @Grienders no, you must add each file.

Comment: I struggled so much with this! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I had faced the same issue which got solved after the following changes.

In HTML pages:

```
{% load static %}  ## loads the static folder and images inside it. 
<div id='button-holder'><img src="{% static "glass.png" %}" alt="Hi!" /></div> ## for images 
                              src="{% static 'my_app/js/app.js' %} ## for scripts.
```

In urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',...
........
 )+ static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

After this run command as @Daniel Roseman have mentioned `python manage.py collectstatic`.  The `findstatic` command can help show you which files are found.
Example

```
python manage.py findstatic css/base.css admin/js/core.js
```

You can find help [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/staticfiles/) regarding it.

Answer (score -1):

You are supposed to run `manage.py collectstatic` to copy your app-level static files to the central static directory.

Comment: This command is called while `manage.py runserver` right ?Any reason so as to run it explicitly ?

Comment: No, it is not run automatically. You need to call it yourself.